# Call dynamic fragment method from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have different Fragments loaded in my activity dynamically by code below

```
Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (pos) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
if(fragment != null){
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frg_container, fragment, "frag_"+pos).commit();
    ITEMPOS = pos;
}
```

Now if I want to call "fragMethod" in one of my fragment, how can I do that? I tried below, but it is not recognizing "fragMethod" unless I put class in front. Now I can't hard code the class as it varies (Fragment1 or Fragment 2).

```
FragmentManager mn = getFragmentManager();
Fragment ft = mn.findFragmentByTag("frag_"+ITEMPOS);
ft.fragMethod(scanResult.toString());
```

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Mike M., I learned to use interface :). Here how it is

Activity Class:

```
public class navContainer extends Activity {
    public interface IFragment
    {
        public void fragMethod(String arg);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
      if (scanResult != null) {
          FragmentManager mn = getFragmentManager();
          Fragment ft = mn.findFragmentByTag("frag_"+ITEMPOS);
          ((IFragment) ft).populateFromBarcode(scanResult.toString());
      }

    }
}
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements IFragment{
    @Override
    public void populateFromBarcode(String isbn){
        System.out.println(isbn);
    }
}
```

Comment: tried `((YourFragmentName)ft).fragMethod(scanResult.toString());` ?

Comment: problem is, "YourFragmentName" is not constant. It can be either Fragment1 or Fragment2 based on the value of pos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `interface`.

```
public interface IFragment
{
    public void fragMethod(String arg);
}

public class Fragment1 implements IFragment {
    public void fragMethod(String arg) {

    }
    ...
}

public class Fragment2 implements IFragment {
    public void fragMethod(String arg) {

    }
    ...     
}
...
...
FragmentManager mn = getFragmentManager();
Fragment ft = mn.findFragmentByTag("frag_"+ITEMPOS);
((IFragment) ft).fragMethod(scanResult.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the method. But I am getting this error: "12-20 11:40:39.512: E/AndroidRuntime(28742): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=-1, data=Intent { act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }} to activity {com.migrationdesk.mylibman/com.migrationdesk.mylibman.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: If I just comment out the last line in your code (that is no function is called), everything becomes okay.

Comment: Nope. Inside fragMethod() in Fragment1, I just put one line System.out.println(arg);

Comment: Updating in my main post. 2 mins. Thanks

Comment: can not, the condition is checked before (please see update). Also, if I just put that fragMethod() inside activity, everything works fine. So, I do get scanResult.

Comment: Then `findFragmentByTag()` is returning null.

Comment: thanks a lot Mike .. This was the case, I had wrong value in ITEMPOS .. awesome solution :)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with 2 ways :

**1. Use instanceof  :**

You can check the fragment as with the use of `instanceof`

```
Fragment ft = mn.findFragmentByTag("frag_" + ITEMPOS);

if (ft instanceof Fragment1) {
    ((Fragment1) ft).fragMethod(scanResult.toString()); 
} else if(ft instanceof Fragment2) {
    ((Fragment2) ft).fragMethod(scanResult.toString()); 
}
```

**2. Use inheritance:**

Define method in your baseClass which extends Fragment and then create all Fragments with extending this `baseClass`

Code snippet :

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public void fragMethod(String arg) {

    }
}
```

Now, you can overrideit in your all Fragments like :

```
public class Fragment1 extends BaseFragment {

    @Override
    public void fragMethod(String arg) {
        super.fragMethod(arg);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: well, it is something new I have learned (thanks for that), but little bit clumsy when I have many fragments, no?